# Java: ExecutorService with Callables: Timeout: future.get() leads to direct break of program

Tags: java, multithreading, timeout, executorservice, callable

I use the ExecutorService in Java and I noticed a behaviour I dont understand.
I use Callable and when I invoke my threads (classes that implement Callable) I set a timeout. Then I wait for the result with `future.get()` and after I wanted to check with `future.isDone()` if a timeout occurs during executing the tasks.

As I read in the documentation for invokeAll with timeout: `returns a list of Futures representing the tasks, in the same sequential order as produced by the iterator for the given task list. If the operation did not time out, each task will have completed. If it did time out, some of these tasks will not have completed.`

So I thought I would get a list of Future results in both cases, if a timeout occurs and if it does not.

What now happens is the following: When a timeout occurs, the code does not go on after `future.get()` and I dont ever get to the point where I could check if a timeout occurs with `future.isDone()`. I dont catch any exception, Im directly leaded to the finally block in my code, which I really dont understand.

here is a snippet of my code:

```
     try {
        // start all Threads
        results = pool.invokeAll(threads, 3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        for (Future<String> future : results)
        {
            try
            {
                // this method blocks until it receives the result, unless there is a 
                // timeout set.
                final String rs = future.get();

                if (future.isDone())
                {
                    // if future.isDone() = true, a timeout did not occur. 
                   // do something
                }
                else
                {
                    // timeout
                    // log it and do something
                    break;
                }
            }
            catch (ExecutionException e)
            {
               // log messages and break, this is a snippet!
            }
            catch (InterruptedException ex)
            {
               // log message and break, this is a snippet!
            }
        }

    }
    catch (InterruptedException ex)
    {
        // log message, this is a snippet!
    }
    finally
    {
        // when a timeout occurs, the code jumps from future.get() directly to this point!
    }
```

Might somebody explain me, why I am not able to reach `future.isDone()` and what I should change to be able to recognize timeouts?

Thank you!

Comment: If you didn't ignore exceptions, you would probably understand what happens.

Comment: How do you come to the conclusion that I ignore them??? Its just a snippet!!! I updated my example.

Comment: Your snippet ignored exceptions, and you have accepted an answer that explains that a CancellationException was thrown, but you didn't see it. That means that this exception was ignored.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are not catching `CancellationException`, which is very likely being thrown after calling `get`. Note that this exception extends `RuntimeException` and the compiler won't warn you to catch it.

Reading the docs for [`invokeAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll%28java.util.Collection,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29):

> *Executes the given tasks, returning a list of Futures holding their status and results when all complete or the timeout expires, whichever happens first. Future.isDone() is true for each element of the returned list. Upon return, **tasks that have not completed are cancelled**.*

Comment: Not possible. IDE says TimeoutException is never thrown in my code.

Comment: Thank you!!! I really did not know that. Now when I catch this CancellationException it works as it is expected to do. So now that Im able to catch this timeout-exception, I do not longer need future.isDone(), correct? If a timeout occurs, it will never reach this point and if no timeout occurs, isDone() will return true in any case, right?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure you are using `invokeAll` correctly. The javadoc says:

> Executes the given tasks, returning a list of Futures holding their
>   status and results when all complete or the timeout expires, whichever
>   happens first. Future.isDone() is true for each element of the
>   returned list.

So what is the point of calling `isDone` since for all the Futures returned `isDone` is true?

Comment: Of course I have code there, this is just a snippet!!! I dont reach the catch Blocks. I have logging messages to check it and I debugged it.

Comment: Are you expecting `future.get` to throw an exception?

Comment: Documentation says: <code>If the operation did not time out, each task will have completed. If it did time out, some of these tasks will not have completed.</code> As I thought Future.isDone() checks for completion, I thought it would return false, if a timeout occurs. It seems like I misread this.

Answer (score 0):

Use isCancelled. If false, that means no timeout. then you can call get() and catch executionException if task did not timeout but had an exception due to any other reason, like nullpointer, assert, etc